# how to change automatically the item id in android listview?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

i have a custom adapter to place items inside listview. To customize it i have a listitem.xml file where i set the elements that compose a listitem.

They are as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a classe Settings.java that uses the following layout settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSettings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#666666"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Class Settings.java is like this:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    private SensorAdapter sensorAdapter;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.title_bar);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        sensorAdapter = new SensorAdapter();

        ListView sensorListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSettings);
        sensorListview.setAdapter(sensorAdapter);                   
        sensorListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                sensorItem sensor = sensorAdapter.getCodeLearnChapter(arg2);

            }
        });
    }

    public class sensorItem {

        String sensorName;
        String sensorDescription;
        Drawable sensorImage;

    }

    public List<sensorItem> getDataForListView() {
        List<sensorItem> sensorsList = new ArrayList<sensorItem>();

        sensorItem sensorGps = new sensorItem();
        sensorGps.sensorName = "Location";
        sensorGps.sensorDescription = "Collect location";
        sensorGps.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location);

        sensorItem sensorPhoto = new sensorItem();
        sensorPhoto.sensorName = "Photos";
        sensorPhoto.sensorDescription = "Collect photos";
        sensorPhoto.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photos);

        sensorItem sensorAmplitude = new sensorItem();
        sensorAmplitude.sensorName = "Sound";
        sensorAmplitude.sensorDescription = "Collect amplitude";
        sensorAmplitude.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.amplitude);

        sensorItem sensorOrientation = new sensorItem();
        sensorOrientation.sensorName = "Orientation";
        sensorOrientation.sensorDescription = "Collect orientation";
        sensorOrientation.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.compass);

        sensorItem sensorSms = new sensorItem();
        sensorSms.sensorName = "Messages";
        sensorSms.sensorDescription = "Collect messages";
        sensorSms.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sms);

        sensorItem sensorBattery = new sensorItem();
        sensorBattery.sensorName = "Battery";
        sensorBattery.sensorDescription = "Collect battery";
        sensorBattery.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.battery);

        sensorItem sensorCalendar = new sensorItem();
        sensorCalendar.sensorName = "Calendar";
        sensorCalendar.sensorDescription = "Collect calendar";
        sensorCalendar.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.calendar);

        sensorItem sensorAccelerometer = new sensorItem();
        sensorAccelerometer.sensorName = "Accelerometer";
        sensorAccelerometer.sensorDescription = "Collect accelerometer";
        sensorAccelerometer.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.accelerometer);

        sensorItem sensorLight = new sensorItem();
        sensorLight.sensorName = "Light";
        sensorLight.sensorDescription = "Collect luminosity";
        sensorLight.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light);

        sensorItem sensorContacts = new sensorItem();
        sensorContacts.sensorName = "Contacts";
        sensorContacts.sensorDescription = "Collect contact";
        sensorContacts.sensorImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.contacts);

        sensorsList.add(sensorGps);
        sensorsList.add(sensorPhoto);
        sensorsList.add(sensorAmplitude);
        sensorsList.add(sensorOrientation);
        sensorsList.add(sensorSms);
        sensorsList.add(sensorBattery);
        sensorsList.add(sensorCalendar);
        sensorsList.add(sensorAccelerometer);
        sensorsList.add(sensorLight);
        sensorsList.add(sensorContacts);

        return sensorsList;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public class SensorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        List<sensorItem> sensorList = getDataForListView();

        private ToggleButton locationToggle, photosToggle, soundToggle,
        orientationToggle, messagesToggle, batteryToggle, calendarToggle,
        accelerometerToggle, lightToggle, contactsToggle;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sensorList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public sensorItem getItem(int arg0) {
            return sensorList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            if (arg1 == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Settings.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, arg2, false);
            }

            TextView sensorDescription = (TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView sensorImage = (ImageView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            locationToggle = (ToggleButton) arg1.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            locationToggle.setChecked(true);

            locationToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "CARREGOU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            sensorItem sensor = sensorList.get(arg0);        
            sensorDescription.setText(sensor.sensorDescription);
            sensorImage.setBackground(sensor.sensorImage);    
            return arg1;
        }

        public sensorItem getCodeLearnChapter(int position) {
            return sensorList.get(position);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem with this is that now every element in the listitem.xml has exactly the same ID.  So every toggle button has the same ID. I dont know which togglebutton the user pressed.

How can i know which togglebutton the user pressed? Do i have to change the way i populate the listview?

Thx very much.

EDIT:

This is how it looks right now and the problem is that the ArrayList that i have to check whether a toggleButton in a row was clicked or not it seems to all set every element to true when i click in another row.

Example:
I have

true | true | true

i click in the third button and i get

true | false | true

but if i click in the first button for example i get

false | true | true

when i should get instead

false | false | true.

Here is the code adapter so someone can take a look.

```
public class SensorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        List<sensorItem> sensorList = getDataForListView();
        private ToggleButton settingsToggle;
        private ArrayList<Boolean> checkedSensors;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sensorList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public sensorItem getItem(int arg0) {
            return sensorList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            if (arg1 == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Settings.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, arg2, false);
            }

            // TextView sensorName = (TextView)
            // arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView sensorDescription = (TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView sensorImage = (ImageView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            settingsToggle = (ToggleButton) arg1.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);          
            settingsToggle.setChecked(true);
            checkedSensors = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 10){
                checkedSensors.add(i,true);
                i++;
            }
            settingsToggle.setTag(new Long(getItemId(arg0)));
            settingsToggle.setOnClickListener(mOnToggleListener);

            /*settingsToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                    if(isChecked){
                        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "on "+buttonView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "off "+buttonView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            });*/

            sensorItem sensor = sensorList.get(arg0);

            // sensorName.setText(sensor.sensorName);
            sensorDescription.setText(sensor.sensorDescription);
            sensorImage.setBackground(sensor.sensorImage);

            return arg1;
        }

        public OnClickListener mOnToggleListener = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                long id = (Long) v.getTag();

                if (checkedSensors.get((int)id)){
                    //enableSensor(id);
                    checkedSensors.add((int)id, false);
                }else{
                    //disableSensor(id);
                    checkedSensors.add((int)id, true);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
                    System.out.println(i + " " + checkedSensors.get(i));
                }

            }
        };

        public sensorItem getSensor(int position) {
            return sensorList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the index in a tag on the toggle button so the onClick event knows which index got clicked.

Before you set the onClick listener add this line:

```
locationToggle.setTag(arg0);
```

And inside your onClick listener:

```
int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
```

Comment: But i only have 1 togglebutton inside the listitem.xml

Comment: You have 1 toggle button per row correct? The tag will let the click listener know which row's toggle button was clicked. Keep in mind that views in a ListView are recycled as they come off the screen.

Comment: i have one toggle button per row. but it is always the same togglebutton in every row. it has the same id.

Comment: It seems you are confused on how this is working. The click listener is connected to the specific instance of a row's toggle button. Even though they have the same id in your `R` file, they are individual objects. As such, it can get confusing when dealing with clicks inside a ListView row. The approach I am trying to show you is by keeping track of the index in the *Object* of the toggleButton, you are able to maintain which row it came from.

Comment: but then if i want to have more togglebuttons how would i set the tag? i had to have arg1 arg2 arg3,.....

Comment: Each toggle button will use arg0. (arg0 = row position)

Comment: If this answered your question, go ahead and mark it as the answer. If not, feel free to update your question.

Comment: when i get this to work i'll give you the correct answer

Comment: how can i see whether the toggleButton at that position is checked or not? any idea? i have this almoust ready. because like this i only now the button at a certain row was clicked. but dont know whether it was set to on or off.

Comment: You can do that with an ArrayList<Boolean> that is updated in your onClick() method for each row. Use the index from the tag.

Comment: I did that i declared the private ArrayList<Boolean> in the class and in the getView method i initialized it with all true values but now when i updated it in clickListener only one gets false. The other return to true if i click in another row.

Comment: Update your question with your new code so I can take a look.

Comment: You are storing the id in the tag instead of the row position. Please replace your tag with the one from my answer as it is the position, rather than the id. There is no reason for keeping track of the id in this scenario. You also don't want to add for each of the click events, but do `sensorList.set(position, boolean)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50718/discussion-between-joaofilipeclementemartins-and-dcharms)

Answer (score 0):

you can create your listener ouside of getView like this:

```
public OnClickListener mOnToggleListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //get id of your item from view
            //v is locationToggleView
            long id = (Long)v.getTag();

        }
};
```

and make these change in getView method:

```
//set id as view tag when create or reuse view
//arg0 is position
locationToggle.setTag(new Long(getItemId(arg0)));
locationToggle.setOnClickListener(mOnToggleListener);
```

by this way you can get view related item id when locationToggle is clicked.

Comment: and i would have to do this part 
locationToggle.setTag(new Long(getItemId(arg0)));
locationToggle.setOnClickListener(mOnToggleListener); only once or i would have to set it for every togglebutton?